# Does $A$ a UFD imply that  $A[T]$ is also a UFD?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

I'm trying to prove that $A$ a UFD implies that $A[T]$ is a UFD.

The only thing I am sure I could try to use is Gauss's lemma.

Also, how can we deduce that the polynomial rings $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ are UFDs?

Comment: Yes (and the proof uses Gauss's Lemma), and induction on $n$.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should know that if $k$ is a field, then $k[x]$ is a UFD (even a Euclidean domain). So given $g(x)\in A[x]$, first write it as $g(x) = cG(x)$, where $c$ is a constant and $G(x)$ is primitive. Then show that a primitive polynomial in $A[x]$ is irreducible if and only if it is irreducible when viewed as a polynomial in $k[x]$, where $k$ is the field of fractions of $A$. Then use this to take an arbitrary polynomial in $A[x]$, and factor it by "factoring out the content, then factoring it over $k[x]$, and then "lifting the factorization" back to $A[x]$. The argument is exactly the same as that used in the case of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ with Gauss's Lemma.

Now, since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a UFD, then by this argument so is $\mathbb{Z}[x_1]$; which means that so is $\mathbb{Z}[x_1][x_2]\cong\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2]$. Which means that so is $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2][x_3] = \mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,x_3]$. Etc. The same holds for polynomials over a field, since a field is trivially a UFD (or because you know that the first polynomial ring, $k[x_1]$, is a UFD).

Comment: I think we alao need to check every irreducible polynomial in $A[X]$ is a prime element, though this is trivial...

Comment: @Bach: That irreducibles are primes follows from the fact that factorizations into irreducibles exist and are unique; it does not need to be proven separately.

Answer (score 19):

There is a slick general way to do this by localization (usually credited to Nagata).  Suppose $\rm\:D\:$ is an *atomic* domain, i.e. nonzero nonunits factor into atoms (irreducibles). If $\rm\:S\:$ is a saturated submonoid of $\rm\:D^*$ (i.e. $\rm\,cd\in S\!\iff c,d\in S)\,$ and, furthermore, $\rm\,S\,$ is generated by primes, then $\rm\: D_S$ UFD $\rm\:\Rightarrow\:D$ UFD. $ $ This is often called *Nagata's Lemma*.

This yields said slick proof of $\rm\:D$ UFD $\,\rm\Rightarrow D[x]$ UFD, viz. $\rm\:S = D^*\:$ is generated by primes, so localizing yields the UFD $\rm\:F[x],\:$ $\rm F =\:$ fraction field of $\rm\:D.\:$ Hence $\rm\:D[x]\:$ is a UFD, by Nagata.

This yields a more conceptual / structural view of the essence of the matter (vs. the traditional argument by Gauss' Lemma). Moreover, the proof generalizes to various rings closely related to GCD domains, e.g. Riesz/Schreier rings, which provide *refinement*-based views of UFDs (which prove more convenient for noncommutative generalizations).

Comment: awesome, but I think you're missing $d\in D^*$ in the definition of saturated submonoid.

Answer (score 8):

The fact that $A$ is a UFD implies that $A[X]$ is a UFD is very standard and can be found in any textbook on Algebra (for example, it is Proposition 2.9.5 in these [notes](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/Algebra/Chapter2.pdf) by Robert Ash). By induction, it now follows that $A[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ is a UFD for all $n\geq 1$.

Comment: Can you please reproduce the proof here for the sake of completeness?

Comment: @JamesR. I thought you were trying to prove it. It's a good exercise to do so yourself, instead of asking someone to do it for you; especially such a standard result.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that I got it down, the concept. I might have messed up on the induction stuff, and wanted to be sure

Comment: @JamesR. Then *say so*, instead of facile statements like "for the sake of completeness". You can post your solution (as an answer, even) and ask people to check it for you.

Comment: @JamesR.If you want to check your proof of the result, the above link should be sufficient. And by the way, this is taken from the second chapter of a wonderful set of notes on abstract algebra. I recommend it!