# Invertible elements in the ring $K[x,y,z,t]/(xy+zt-1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I would like to know how big is the set of invertible elements in the ring $$R=K[x,y,z,t]/(xy+zt-1),$$ where $K$ is any field. In particular whether any invertible element is a (edit: scalar) multiple of $1$, or there is something else. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In any ring, every element is a multiple of 1. What did you mean to ask?

Comment: @Hurkyl: I assume "multiple of $1$" in this context means scalar multiple of $1$ (that is, element of $K$).

Comment: @Hurkyl: Thank you for your comment. Indeed, I meant to say scalar multiple of 1, that is any element of the form a*1 with a in K\{0}. I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: In http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173021/is-the-coordinate-ring-of-sl2-a-ufd it is shown your ring is a UFD.  I doubt this helps to find units, but if you continue working with the ring, it could be quite helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a geometric proof that $R^*=K^*$.

Embedd $U=\operatorname{Spec}R$ as an open subvariety into the projective variety 
$$P:=\operatorname{Proj} K[x,y,z,t, w]/(xy+zt-w^2).$$
Note that $xy+zt-w^2$ is irreducible over an algebraic closure of $K$, so $P$ is geometrically integral, hence ${\mathcal O}_P(P)=K$. Using Jacobian criterion, we see that $P$ is smooth, hence normal.

Let $f\in R^*$ that we consider as a rational function on $P$. As $E:=P\setminus U$ is the zero set of $w$ which is an integral hypersurface in $P$, the divisor of $f$ 
is $\mathrm{div}(f)=nE$ for some integer $n$. If $n\ge 0$, then $f$ has no pole on $P$, so $f\in {\mathcal O}_P(P)=K$ (because $P$ is normal). If $n<0$, then the same reasonning applied to $1/f$ shows that $1/f\in K$. In both cases, $f\in K$.

---

**EDIT 2.** *Please forget the wrong answer below.*

**Edit.** Simply the former proof thanks to the comments of the OP.

The only invertible elements are in $K^*$. I don't really like the proof below, but for the moment I don't have an alternative one.

In $R$, the relation $tz=1-xy$ implies that any element
$f(x,y,z,t)\in R$ can be written as
$$f(x,y,z,t)=g(x,y,z)+th(x,y).$$
Suppose $f$ is invertible in $R$. Let $K^a$ be an algebraic closure of $K$.
Denote by 
$$Z=\{(a,b,c,d)\in (K^a)^4 \mid ab+cd=1\}.$$ 
Then $f(a,b,c,d)\ne 0$ for all $(a,b,c,d)\in Z$.

<s>First observation: there is no common factor $h_1(x,y)$ of $g(x,y,z)$ and
$h(x,y)$ because otherwise $h_1(x,y)$ would be invertible in $R$, but
for any $(a,b)\in (K^a)^2$, there exists $(a,b,c,d)\in Z$, so $h_1(a,b)\ne 0$,
thus $h_1(x,y)\in K^*$.</s>

Now for any $(a,b,c)\in (K^a)^3$ such that $c\ne 0$ <s>and $h(a,b)\ne 0$,</s>
we have $g(a,b,c)+(1-ab)h(a,b)/c \ne 0$ because otherwise
$f(a,b,c,d)=0$ with $d=(1-ab)/c$ and $(a,b,c,d)\in Z$.
This means that in the affine space $\mathbb A^3_K$, we have
$$ V(zg(x,y,z)+(1-xy)h(x,y))\subseteq V(z).$$
Therefore $z \mid f$ and $h=0$.

We are now reduced to the situation $f=g(x,y,z)$. Similar reasoning
show that $g(x,y,z)=\lambda z^n$ with $\lambda \in K^*$ and
$n\ge 0$. Again we see as above that $n>0$ is impossible. So
$f\in K^*$.

Comment: Could you please explain, why do you need $h(a,b)\neq 0$ in the paragraph that starts with "Now for any $(a,b,c)\in (K^a)^3$..."? 
It looks like you only use that $c\neq 0$ when you write d=(1-ab)/c.

Comment: You are right. So the proof is simpler.

Comment: Your assertion "...any element
$f(x,y,z,t)\in R$ can be written as
$f(x,y,z,t)=g(x,y,z)+th(x,y).$" is not true. It is false for $t^2$, for example .

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg, thanks ! But then I don't see how to repair. :(

Comment: Sorry about that, Cantlog, but it is not so important: your geometric argument is very beautiful and I upvoted it the moment I saw it. I strongly urge user 26565 to accept it and other users to upvote it.

Comment: I'm trying to learn this sort of approach. I believe I know such things as "the number of poles is the number of zeros" and "all the bad stuff happens on E". I believe "the divisor of f is a multiple of E" is stating that f cannot have both poles and zeros on E. Can someone describe why that is so?

Comment: @Cantlog Thank you! The geometric argument is very nice. I will accept it, since I understand how it works for a field $K$. However, as I imply from your terminology ("geometrically integral" etc.) that it is valid for some rings $K$ which are not necessarily fields. Could you please tell whether your argument is valid for all rings $K$?

Comment: @JackSchmidt I don't know much about algebraic geometry, and to understand argument, I looked in the Basic Geometric Geometry by Shafarevich, vol 1, 2 ed. Here (p. 154) it is proved that if $P$ is smooth and irreducible then if $div f\geq 0$ (that is, any coefficient in $div f$ is $\geq 0$) then $f$ is regular function. To prove it, Shafarevich assumes that $f$ is not regular at $x\in P$ and considers the local ring $O_x$. Since $f=g/h$ for some $g,h\in O_x$, $f\not\in O_x$ and $O_x$ is UFD, exists $\pi\in O_x$ which divides $h$ but not $g$. Then $div f$ at a component $C$ of $V(\pi)$ is $<0$.

Comment: @user26565, the proof above is specific to the case when $K$ is a field. In general, the results doesn't hold, e.g. if $K$ is a ring with nilpotent elements, then $1+v\in R^*$ is a unit in $R$ for any nilpotent $v$. But this is probably the only possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R=K[X,Y,Z,T]/(XY+ZT-1)$. In the following we denote by $x,y,z,t$ the residue classes of $X,Y,Z,T$ modulo the ideal $(XY+ZT-1)$. Let $f\in R$ invertible. Then its image in $R[x^{-1}]$ is also invertible. But $R[x^{-1}]=K[x,z,t][x^{-1}]$ and $x$, $z$, $t$ are algebraically independent over $K$. Thus $f=cx^n$ with $c\in K$, $c\ne0$, and $n\in\mathbb Z$. Since $R/xR\simeq K[Z,Z^{-1}][Y]$ we get that $x$ is a prime element, and therefore $n=0$. Conclusion: if $f$ is invertible, then $f\in K-\{0\}$.

Comment: I'm strongly reminded of the reasoning I gave in Bungo's question on associates (now buried in one of the many edits): anyway +1. I wonder just how far this type of reasoning with the units can be extended...