# units and irreducible elements over UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra

Pick out the correct statements from the following list:

a. A homomorphic image of a UFD (unique factorization domain) is again a
UFD.

b. The element $2 \in \mathbb Z[\sqrt{−5}]$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{−5}]$.

c. Units of the ring $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{−5}]$ are the units of $\mathbb Z$.

d. The element $2$ is a prime element in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{−5}]$.

Comment: What are your thoughts ? Any guess ?

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself. Also, many would consider your post rude because it is a command ("Pick"), not a request for help, so please consider rewriting it.

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with LaTeX, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting.

Comment: my confusion arises between b and d..

Comment: @ARIJITPAL: Have you looked at the wikipedia articles on [irreducible elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element) and [prime elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element)? Do you understand that they are not the same concept?

Comment: @ZevChonoles you are absolutely correct that am new in that site..and thanks for the advice ..

Comment: same:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221527/some-question-related-to-mathbbz-sqrt-5-and-ufd?rq=1