# Product of gcd and lcm for multivariate polynomials

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

This maybe trivial but I don't know how to conclude the proof. Consider the ring of multivariate polynomials with field coefficients $K[X_1,\dots,X_n]$. Take two nonzero polynomials $F$ and $G$ and prove:

$$FG=\gcd(F,G)lcm(F,G)$$

Since such ring is not Bezout I don't know how to prove this. I managed to prove that their gcd and their lcm both divide their product but I don't know how to do the converse relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ring [is a UFD](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/150936/242) so a GCD domain. As [proved here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/88411/242) the identity holds true in any GCD domain.

It can also be proved via prime factorizations, but that is less general than said proof using gcd laws.