# Show that there exist $a,b \in K [X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n]$ and $d \in K[X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_{n-1}]$ such that $aF+bG = d.$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, gcd-and-lcm, coprime

> > Let $K$ be a field. Let $F,G \in K [X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n]$ be two polynomials which are relatively prime to each other. Show that there exist polynomials $a,b \in  K [X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n]$ and $0 \neq d \in K [X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_{n-1}]$ such that $aF+bG = d.$

How do I prove it? Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your question is odd: I can take $a, b, d$ to be $0$, then the equality hold trivially.
It should rather be something like: for all $d$ there exist $a, b$..
Moreover: What is relatively prime in your definition?

Comment: Yeah you are correct @kesa. I have edited now accordingly.

Comment: What are your attempts to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There may be a positive answer in [here](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~tannala/gradu.pdf) for $n = 3$. (I can't comment)

Trying to generalize it:

Since $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ [is a UFD](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150917/does-a-a-ufd-imply-that-at-is-also-a-ufd), $a,b$ as members of $k(x_1,...,x_{n-1})[x_n]$, a PID, have no common factors ([Gauss's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial))). Then you get $af + bg = 1$ and clearing denominators of $f,g$ you have the desired result.